# compile the my own matlab function to be a C++ library

Tags: c++, matlab

In my main `matlab` function, some m functions written by myself and some built-in matlab functions are called. If I use the maltab compiler `mcc` to compile these called m functions to be a `C++` library, and also compile the main matlab function, is it possible that I could call this main function in my `C++` scripts ? Or how could I achieve this goal? Is it a must to convert the main `matlab` function to a `C++` function? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is an example to explain my question more clearly:

```
function y = mymain(m,n)
     ...
     a = randn(m,n);
     b = find(a>0);
     c = sqrt(b);
     d = myfun1(b);
     e = myfun2(c); % myfun1 and myfun2 are the subfunctions written by my self 
     ...
     % in myfun1 and myfun2, only the matlab build-in functions are called.
     % my goal is to get the point that a C++ main function could call this mymain
```

Comment: My platform is Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to build a dynamic link-libary *.so for my matlab program.

Comment: I've classified this is achievable.